# Unable to parse javascript tag inside ace editor while loading from database

Tags: javascript, php, ace-editor

I am using [Live-HTML-CSS-Code-Editor](https://github.com/78526Nasir/Live-HTML-CSS-Code-Editor) to run HTML CSS javascript code on the browser that is working properly.

I saved all my codes in MySQL database tables from there I am showing the code to my editor
this is working properly for HTML and CSS.

I am facing the problem if fetched database code has any `</script>`  tag in it like

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
or any embeded `<script>......</script>` tag it in not showing code in ace editor

my ace editor code is 
https://github.com/78526Nasir/Live-HTML-CSS-Code-Editor/blob/master/index.html

using PHP to load data in the editor
 and showing data in the editor as follow

```
editor.setValue(`<?php echo $result[0]['code']; ?>`, 1);
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

When adding text to html page with php you need to use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent it from being interpretted as html.

Comment: Html special char are shoing my code like &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt;

Comment: I want to display with tags